# Viewing .pgm images in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pgm

I have been provided with a dataset consisting of .pgm images to be used for some coding in Matlab. I was just wondering if it is possible to view the same image as a .jpeg/.png in Matlab itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

To visualize the image in matlab,

```
imshow(imread('im.pgm'))
```

To convert the image from `pgm` to `jpeg`:

```
imwrite(imread('im.pgm'),'im.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

The MathWorks docs on [imread](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html) seem to suggest Matlab can read in a pgm file.

Showing it should be a matter of using `imshow` on the resulting array returned by `imread`.