# convert a pgm image to jpg Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to convert the image found here [pgm image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kfxsf286zu47as0/00000001.pgm) to jpg but I can't. I've tried the answer of the question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823854/viewing-pgm-images-in-matlab) but it didn't work. So, if anyone could please advise.

Comment: Are you sure the file is not corrupted? even imagemagick's `identify` tool cant read it. Do you have any other files? Can you open this file in some other program?

Comment: i've tried opening it using Gimp but it didn't work, thats why I thought may be there is another problem. I'll check another file and will get back to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your file-header:

```
Pf 640 480 9757
```

According to [Wikidepida](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Anymap#Graymap) and [this man page](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) your file should use `P2` (for the graymap) instead of `Pf` (which seems to be invalid in all cases):

```
P2 640 480 9757
```

With that little change (made in a text editor) your file opens fine.

Comment: I'm now trying to convert this file to .jpg using the answer suggested in the question but it gives this error "UINT16 image data requires bitdepth specifically set to either 12 or 16." so any advise please?

Comment: Check [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html)! Scroll down until you find **'BitDepth' — Number of bits per pixel** - you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more faces use the [Cambridge's database](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/facedatabase.html)
And do it like in your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823854/viewing-pgm-images-in-matlab).

$> im = imread( 'file.pgm' );

$> imwrite( im , 'nameForJpg.jpg');

And that's it!

Good Luck!

Live long and prosper!